# keep leading zeros only while reversing a number in java

Tags: java

I am doing my assignment question which is to "reverse a number keep the leading zeros and remove the trailing zeros also keep the sign as it is".

If I reverse it taking  as a integer, it will remove leading as well as trailing zeros and if I reverse it taking  as a string, it will keep all the zeros.
Can anyone help me only keeping the leading zeros.

For example "-00360" should be "-6300".

problem-

Write a Java function to accept a number and return the reverse of the same. If the number ends with one or more zeros, then in the reversed number those zeros will not be present (since those zeros become leading zeros). If the input number is negative, the sign should be retained. ##Examples  Input:   -123  Output:   -321  Input:   1123400  Output:   43211

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your specific programming problem?

Comment: `String s = new StringBuilder("00360").reverse().toString().replaceFirst("^[0]+" "");`

Comment: another question, @Dan how would i preserve the sign  if i will reverse it using a string?

Comment: U would solve it using some kind of a loop (for, while..) and an if statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In below codes, you can reverse the negative and positive numbers. On method `reversedString(String num)`, you can reverse your numbers. `String reverseNumKeeper()` helps you to keep your new reversed number. With using for loop, you reverse the number, 123 => 321. Then, you should check if the new reversed String has a negative sign, if has, you should add it in front of number, else, just return new reversed number.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Reverse {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter number");
        //input
        String number = scanner.next();

        System.out.println(Reverse.reversedString(number));

    }

    private static String reversedString(String num) {

        String reverseNumKeeper = "";
        //reverse number with and without negative sign
        for (int i = num.length(); i > 0; i--) {
            reverseNumKeeper += num.charAt(i - 1);
        }

        //check if reverseNumKeeper has a negative sign or not
        if (reverseNumKeeper.contains("-")) {
            return "-" + Integer.parseInt(reverseNumKeeper.replace("-", ""));
        } else {
            return "" + Integer.parseInt(reverseNumKeeper);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: this way i would also have trailing zeros in the output.i only need leading zeros fir eg. "-0360"->"-0630" but i need "-360"

Comment: @anmolhans, you have mentioned on your post:
**For example "-00360" should be "-6300".**
Code that I have written outputs the -6300 as well.
`Enter number`
`-0360`
`-630`

Answer (score 0):

Well as [YCF_L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5558072/ycf-l) said you can just use a `StringBuilder` having a negative there does not make to much difference. You can include a check for it.

```
public class FunWithNumbers {
    public static int numberReverser(String number) {
        System.out.println("Input: " + number);

        int returnVal;
        String returnString;
        boolean negative = false;

        //If minus is always at the start if it is there
        if(number.substring(0, 1).equals("-")) {
            negative = true;
        }

        if(negative) {
            returnString = new StringBuilder(number.substring(1, number.length() - 1)).reverse().toString().replaceFirst("^[0]+", "");
            returnString = "-" + returnString;
        } else {
            returnString = new StringBuilder(number).reverse().toString().replaceFirst("^[0]+", "");
        }

        try {
            returnVal = Integer.parseInt(returnString);
        } catch (NumberFormatException nFE) {
            System.out.println("There was a number format exception");
            returnVal = -1;
        }

        System.out.println("Output: " + returnVal + "\n");
        return returnVal;
    }

    public static int numberReverser(int number) {
        return numberReverser(Integer.toString(number));
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Usage
        FunWithNumbers.numberReverser("003600");
        FunWithNumbers.numberReverser("-003600");

        FunWithNumbers.numberReverser((int)0036000D);
        FunWithNumbers.numberReverser((int)-003600D);
    }
}
```

---

Output

```
Input: 003600
Output: 6300

Input: -003600
Output: -6300

Input: 36000
Output: 63

Input: -3600
Output: -63
```

You might notice that there are two ways of inputting it here, but only one will give you the correct output you are after.

The first way if with a `String`. This provides the expected output. The second method, with an `int` does not provide the expected output. This is because an int will not store the leading zeros. Similarly, if you attempt to input an int with leading zeros, you can actually convert it to octal. To avoid this you can use `(int)<int>D` or `(int)<int>F`. See the example in the code